# Javascript how to pass mutliple parameters

Tags: javascript, c, function, parameters, console

So as a C user, I really love using `printf`. Now that I'm doing js applications I'm forced to use `console.log()`. You can use `console.log("User %s has %d points", userName, userPoints);`, but i want to create my own function to do the job, because im making a few changes. So I want to create a function that takes multiple parameters, and print them out accordingly.

Example of what i want to do

```
function(parm1,parm2,parm3...){
  //Stuff
}
console.log("number:%d text:%s"par1,par2);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, omg i cant believe that i just didnt search JavaScript spring. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). like this

```
function p(){
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
        console.log(arguments[i]);
}

p(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Yup this works. Ill try to turn it into my own printf statement before downloading. https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js

Comment: Why would you do that if it is initially supported by the browser (e.g. Google Chrome)?

Comment: However, i would like to create my own sprinf method not use another persons code.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I'm creating my own function.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the default implementation of `console.log()`, because it *does* support multiple arguments, like it is described in the [reference guide of the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Console/log) and in the [reference guide of Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object).

Your example does also work with console.log (taken from the [official developer page of Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object)):

```
console.log("User %s has %d points", userName, userPoints);
```

Comment: Yeah but i cant do stuff like this console.log("number:%d text:%s"par1,par2);

Comment: You can. See my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome. thanks BLUEPIXY also gave a good answer, i was trying to recreate my own console.log method, but this method works as well. Thanks, i wish i could have two answers.

Answer (score 1):

console log can take multi arguments, so you can use like :

```js
    var a = function(parm1,parm2,parm3,param4,param5){
      console.log(parm1,parm2,parm3); 
    }
    
    a(1,2,3)
```

you could run the snippets and see in your dev tool.

Comment: Sorry i meant, i wanted to created something that i can do this with. console.log("number:%d text:%s"par1,par2);

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar output

```
console.log('param1 = ' + param1 = ' param2 = ' + param2);
```

Also there is debug mode in most of browsers where you can use breakpoints.

Comment: Yeah i know i can do that. I don’t want to do it that way. I want to do it like printf, console.log("number:%d text:%s"par1,par2);